# WPF-C# StackPanel Visibility and ToggleButton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using C# and WPF to write a program which has a side menu like the one in the screenshot below.

[image]

The XAML Code for Menu Toggle Button 4 and 5 looks like this:

```xml
<ToggleButton x:Name="MenuBtn_4" Content="MENU TOGGLE BUTTON 4" />
<StackPanel x:Name="Submenu_4" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MenuBtn_4, 
    Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, 
    FallbackValue=Visible}">
    <Button Content="SUBMENU BUTTON 1" />
    <Button Content="SUBMENU BUTTON 2" />
</StackPanel>

<ToggleButton x:Name="MenuBtn_5" Content="MENU TOGGLE BUTTON 5" />
<StackPanel x:Name="Submenu_5" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MenuBtn_5, 
    Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, 
    FallbackValue=Visible}">
    <Button Content="SUBMENU BUTTON 1" />
    <Button Content="SUBMENU BUTTON 2" />
</StackPanel>
```

Right now if I click on the Menu`ToggleButton`, the `StackPanel` with Submenu Buttons below becomes visible. If I click the `ToggleButton` again it collapses, which is what I want.
But if the `StackPanel` of one Menu `ToggleButton` is visible and I click on another `ToggleButton` the first one stays visible. I would like it so that when another Menu `ToggleButton` is checked, the previously visible stack panels of the other Menu toggle buttons collapse. I tried solving this with `MultiBinding` but I cannot seem to make it work. Does anyone have any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: You could do that in code-behind I presume

Comment: why not using expander?

Comment: and more specificity on `I tried solving this with MultiBinding but I cannot seem to make it work` i.e. your code + what didn't work

Comment: Also, what do you want to happen when both your ToggleButtons are checked at the same time? With your current requirements, no menu would be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing such issue just because your window allows to check multiple `ToggleButtons`. Your issue can be resolved by implementing a logic which allows only one `ToggleButton` to be selected at a time.

And for this, you can use `RadioButton` which looks like ToggleButton in UI.

```
<RadioButton x:Name="MenuBtn_4" Content="MENU TOGGLE BUTTON 4" GroupName="grp1"
                              Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" cal:Message.Attach="MenuSelect"/>
                <StackPanel x:Name="Submenu_4" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MenuBtn_4, 
                    Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, 
                    FallbackValue=Visible}">
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MenuBtn}" Content="SUBMENU BUTTON 1"
                            cal:Message.Attach="SubmenuSelect"/>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MenuBtn}" Content="SUBMENU BUTTON 2"
                            cal:Message.Attach="SubmenuSelect"/>
                </StackPanel>

<RadioButton x:Name="MenuBtn_5" Content="MENU TOGGLE BUTTON 5" GroupName="grp1"
                              Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" cal:Message.Attach="MenuSelect"/>
                <StackPanel x:Name="Submenu_5" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MenuBtn_5, 
                    Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, 
                    FallbackValue=Visible}">
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MenuBtn}" Content="SUBMENU BUTTON 1"
                            cal:Message.Attach="SubmenuSelect"/>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MenuBtn}" Content="SUBMENU BUTTON 2"
                            cal:Message.Attach="SubmenuSelect"/>
                </StackPanel>
```

NOTE: if you can see, I have used style `{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}` but I think it should also work with your custom style `{StaticResource ToggleMenuBtn}`. But that you need to check.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I just changed my ToggleButtons to RadioButtons and added the GroupName. I did not know RadioButtons worked like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MultiDataTrigger` in a `Style` instead of a `MultiBinding`, causing each `StackPanel` to be visible only when the `ToggleButton` is checked and the other `ToggleButton` is not.

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="MenuBtn_4" Content="MENU TOGGLE BUTTON 4" Margin="0 5 0 5"/>
    <StackPanel x:Name="Submenu_4">
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=MenuBtn_4, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=MenuBtn_5, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
        <StackPanel.Triggers>
        </StackPanel.Triggers>
        <Button Content="SUBMENU BUTTON 1" />
        <Button Content="SUBMENU BUTTON 2" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ToggleButton x:Name="MenuBtn_5" Content="MENU TOGGLE BUTTON 5" Margin="0 5 0 5"/>
    <StackPanel x:Name="Submenu_5">
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=MenuBtn_5, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=MenuBtn_4, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
        <Button Content="SUBMENU BUTTON 1" />
        <Button Content="SUBMENU BUTTON 2" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

However, this won't force any `ToggleButton` to get unchecked when you check the other, and that's because **it's not a correct use of the `ToggleButton` class**. If you want truly exclusive behavior, you can use `RadioButton` as suggested in another answer or you could change the user experience by displaying sub menus *when the mouse is over* one of the header buttons instead of when a header is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

As "**quick and dirty**" you can solve it with XAML only if you put a hidden `RadioButton` and `RadioButton`s have a property `GroupName`, which provides that only one `RadioButton` is checked:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb11" GroupName="G1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="tb11" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rb11}"  Content="111" />
    <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rb11, Converter={StaticResource Convert}}">
        <TextBlock Text="1111111111"/>
        <TextBlock Text="1111111111"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb22" GroupName="G1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="tb22" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rb22}" Content="222" />
    <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rb22, Converter={StaticResource Convert}}">
        <TextBlock Text="22222222222"/>
        <TextBlock Text="22222222222"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```